# react native flatlist jumps items periodically until reaches specific item

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I'm using `Flatlist` and list items **don't have specific height**, when I want to scroll to a specific index it's not scrolling to an exact item, and **takes a while** to go to that item.

[**this is the video of the problem**](https://youtu.be/_5jYTXd41g8)

when I use `this.flatlist.scrollToindex()`, I get the error `flatlist.scrollToindex() is not a function` so I use :

```js
this.flatList.scrollToItem({
  animated: true,
  item: item,
  viewPosition: 0.5,
});
```

this is the component which has a flatlist inside and **doesn't have getItemLayout** function:

```js
<CustomFlatList
  header={headerComponent}
  inverted={renderAsChat || invertedList}
  style={[
    postStyles.dashboardContainer,
    isLonelyPost && { backgroundColor: '#fff' },
  ]}
  loading={loading}
  onRefresh={customRefresh === true ? refresh : this.onRefresh}
  content={content}
  pageTabTitle={pageTabTitle}
  renderItem={({ item, key, index }) =>
    this.renderPostItem(item, index, pageTabTitle)
  }
  emptyMessage={emptyMessage}
  keyExtractor={(item, key) => this.getItemKey(item)}
  loadMore={customLoadMore === true ? loadMore : this.loadMore}
  scrollState={this.state.sendPostButtonVisible}
  changeScrollState={this.changeScrollState}
  navigation={navigation}
  onViewableItemsChanged={this.onVideoExitScreen}
  enableLoadMore={enableLoadMore && !isLonelyPost}
  yOffsetThreshold={1000}
  ref={(ref) => { this.flatList = ref; }}
/> : <View />
```

Comment: are you tried this with "animated: false" ?

Comment: @novonimo didn't help